# Creating an online ide, security risk

Tags: javascript, php, git, ide

I am on a personal project of creating a web-based ide, or lets say, just a text-editor, and the app would allow users to register and start their own javascript project.

The backend language that would write the files is php.

### Questions.

1. How do I safely write user-input files into server, having a `fwrite` would mean that I can write everything on the server, and would definitely be a major security issue.

#### If.

- I wonder if I could implement dvcs (distributed version control), e.g. git (heroku, github), service and ask php to `git push` the files to the repository, would that save me from the issue?
- If I just store his codes, the file type, and the content to a database, would that make sense?

Comment: For the most part this is abstract, but IMHO the question appears to be less of "how to safely save code" and more of "who can save code".  In other words, for your particular app, individuals whose code you are going to save - without reviewing yourself - should be vetted so only be those whom you trust to save code in the fashion you are referring can actually do so.

Comment: so in short, this is quite impossible?

Comment: Not impossible, more like improbable from a security standpoint.  To me this is more of a trust issue vs. coding issue.  What you are dealing with isn't of the nature of whether or not you can make such a feature, but whether someone can abuse the system - which you appear to already be aware of based on your question.

Comment: Ahh, right, I guess I'll stop worrying about it, since I will just develop a prototype system and will only allow trusted people to test it. But I'll keep the question open for possible solutions.